# How to solve this error : TypeError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index

Tags: python, pandas

Getting error  :- **'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index**

```
def create_excel_file():
    master_list = []
    for name in filelist:
        new_path = Path(name).parent
        base = os.path.basename(new_path)
        final = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
        with open(name,"r") as f:
            soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

        df = pd.DataFrame([(x["uri"], *x["t"].split("T"), x["u"], x["desc"])
                           for x in soupObj.find_all("log")],
                          columns=["Document", "Date", "Time", "User", "Description"])
        df.insert(0, 'Database', f'{final}')
        df['Document'] = df['Document'].astype(str)
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
        master_list.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(master_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True).set_index('Date').last('3M')
    df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
    df.to_excel("logfile.xlsx", index=True)

create_excel_file()
```

suggest me what I am doing wrong

**Error message:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\project\Final test.py", line 40, in <module>
    create_excel_file()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\project\Final test.py", line 34, in create_excel_file
    df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True).set_index('Date').last('3M')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 9001, in last
    raise TypeError("'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index")
TypeError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index

Process finished with exit code 1
```

getting Error as shows above

Comment: Can you add full error message?

Comment: Error message added

Comment: Could you provide a sample `dict` of what you working on as text or better a [mcve] May take a read short read of how to create [mcve] thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html)

> For a DataFrame with a sorted DatetimeIndex, this function selects the last few rows based on a date offset.

So, you need to make sure that you did your sort on a column whose values are of type Datetime

From your code below, make sure the data in column 'Date' are actually datetime

`df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True).set_index('Date').last('3M')`